# Lengths as equivalence classes

Tags: euclidean-geometry, set-theory

From Wikipedia on [cardinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Formal_definition):

> The oldest definition of the **cardinality** of a set $X$ (implicit in
>   Cantor and explicit in Frege and Principia Mathematica) is as the
>   class $[X]$ of all sets that are equinumerous with $X$.

My question is simple:

> Who was the first to state explicitly that the **length** of a line
>   segment $l$ is the class $[l]$ of all line
>   segments that are equal to $l$ (in the sense of Euclid)? And who can be assumed to have known or considered this implicitly? Euclid himself?

---

Probably not the first but a very important author did state it like this:

[image]

(Hartshorne, [Geometry: Euclid and beyond](http://euclid.colorado.edu/~wtaylor/agi.pdf) (1997), p. 3)

Comment: Explicitly? I may be wrong, but I would guess some educator after 1950 (Maybe [Piaget](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272840/source-for-analysis-of-identification-of-structures-in-learners-mind-and-mathem)?) :-) See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135347/who-introduced-the-terms-equivalence-relation-and-equivalence-class

Comment: How did you guess? And why so late? The idea is very obvious, isn't it?

Comment: This is the first time I saw length defined as an equivalence class, could you provide a reference where it is done? I suspect that not only nobody treated it this way "implicitly", but even whoever did it explicitly had to maintain some serious effort to think of it this way. Dedekind cuts do come to mind, as well as Hilbert's construction of real numbers out of geometry axioms using segments.

Comment: “Obvious” *to us*, maybe. E.g. Hilbert in *Grundlagen der Geometrie* ([1899](//archive.org/details/grundlagendergeo00hilb/page/23), [translation](//archive.org/details/foundationsofgeo00hilb/page/32)) still defines length as $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}$ and *congruence* of segments as equality of their length, not vice versa.

Comment: But Euclid had only congruence, no length.

Comment: I haven't read Euclid in detail, but did he actually call line segments "equal" if they could be isometrically transformed to each other (using modern parlance)?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold That would have been a natural thing for him to do. But, conjecturally for philosophical reasons related to doubts about the use of motion in geometry, he avoids the use of congruence as much as possible, see [commentary to I.4](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI4.html). Hence, proliferation of triangles in many demonstrations, where congruence would have simplified the clutter.

Comment: If it's not congruence: what else  lets Euclid say that two line segments are equal?

Comment: @Conifold interesting. So for him the only thing that can distinguish two line segments is their length. Or put differently: the length is the same thing as the line segment?

Comment: @HansStricker In practice, equality of triangles. He "grudgingly" uses congruence in I.8 to get SSS, then derives ASA and SAS from it. After that he does not need any definition of equality to prove it for given segments, he just builds enough triangles around them and derives it from *their* equality. So what functions as an implicit definition is: segments are equal if they are matching sides of equal triangles. It has been suggested that he could make SSS a postulate and wipe out congruence altogether, but I guess that pushes it too far. He already had the parallel postulate to wrestle.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold For Euclid there is no such thing as length. The whole idea of distinguishing things by assigning numbers or algebraic objects to them is very modern, nominalist, and alien to Greeks. Segments are distinguished because they are existent entities, geometers take them as they find them. They do compare them and put them together, but they do not "map" them into a different category or hypostatize equivalence classes of them.

Comment: @Conifold, thanks. Do you happen to know when the concept of the "length of a line segment" arose, if it was alien to the greeks. I imagine that the Greeks did already measure lengths of things in everyday practice (say the length of a piece of cloth). How would they call that?

Comment: @Conifold: But when specifically did they say that two distinct triangles are equal? What has to be the case?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold They did, of course, as did Egyptian rope stretchers to whom we owe the name "geometry". But measuring was seen as "corrupting" the purity of science by Plato et al. (it was ok in astronomy though). These strictures and the walls between numbers and magnitudes crumbled slowly in Islamic mathematics, but they were still in play by the end of 16th century. Vieta and Stevin deserve much credit for taking them down in Europe.

Comment: @HansStricker When SSS, ASA or SAS applies. They require some segments to be already known as equal, but those can be given or Euclid can create them using the circle postulate, etc. He has no need for "general definition".

Comment: @Conifold Thanks. I'm puzzled by the fact that greeks considered measuring a corruption of science. To my mind, measuring a length (of a line segment or whatever) just means putting that length into proportion with another length. And I thought that greeks did that quite frequently in geometry, hence to my mind they measured lengths. So either I'm mistaken about what greeks did in geometry, or they had a different conception of what it means to measure lengths. If you can recommend literature on the matter I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold A ratio of segment to segment (or magnitude to magnitude) equated to another ratio (including of numbers) is indeed ubiquitous. But to get the benefits of real numbers ("measuring") one needs to identify ratios with segments themselves and transplant the algebra onto them. For that one needs to arbitrarily fix a universal *unit* segment. Greeks were not up for admitting a ruler. Good source on early practice is [Fowler's Mathematics of Plato's Academy](https://archive.org/stream/MathematicsOfPlatosAcademyFowler/Mathematics_of_Plato%27s_Academy-Fowler_djvu.txt)

Comment: @Conifold: Concerning your question in your first comment: please see the quotation from Hartshorne I added to my question.

Comment: Arithmetic of line segments was introduced by Descartes in La Geometrie (1637), but he did not construe of it as length being an equivalence class. He picked a fixed segment as "unit" and then showed how to multiply two segments using it as an auxiliary (addition does not require a unit segment). Hartshorne seems to be channeling Hilbert's Grundlagen (possibly with extra abstraction added).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, Euclid understood this. Probably. (It is very difficult to speculate
what a person who lived 2300 years ago, and about whom we really know nothing, understood). Euclid's Elements was rigorously formalized by Hilbert
(Foundations of Geometry, end of 19th century, there are translations to many languages, including English). He essentially corrected what Euclid "probably understood but could not express well", and filled many gaps in Euclid.

This includes the notion of length. In the modern approach length is a function on the set of intervals which takes values in real numbers. This is equivalent to what you say. Equivalence relation a set is mathematically the same as a function on the set (which sends an element of the set to its equivalence class).

For a very accessible discussion of this and other questions about Euclid's Elements I recommend the book by R. Hartshorne, Geometry. Euclid and beyond.
Hilbert's book is also very readable. But on my opinion, Hartshorne is the best. One can also read Euclid, but this is difficult, and it is recommended to read him with modern comments (by Heath or Hartshorne).

Comment: Euclid, "Common Notion I" ... *Things which equal the same thing also equal one another.*